# Fix JSON by adding quotes around URLS

Tags: java, json

Hi I've got some (badly formed - I know) JSON via Google Analaytics for example:

```
[[parliament.nz, /en-nz/about-parliament/visiting/virtual-tour, 2469, 9.011340623734306, 496.3847711624139], [parliament.nz, /en-nz/about-parliament/history-buildings/buildings/virtual-tour, 949, 7.804004214963119, 367.6933614330875],
```

I want to put some quotes around those paths because the '/'s are causing a problem in the next stage of the processing.

I know how to remove them using replaceAll, which is a bit ugly.

Is there a way to put quotes around the whole path so the /s don't interrupt the processing?

Comment: Does Google returns such results? It is not badly-formed, it is not even a JSON.

Comment: Yes they do from the Java Analytics API.  Anything useful you can add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest solution, is to have a library do it for you.

E.g. Apache Commons [StringEscapeUtils.escapeJson(String input)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJson(java.lang.String)).

Otherwise you are going to have to deal with corner cases yourself.

Tokenize the input string then escape the paths, or escape the entire line then embed.